# file_get_html returning empty page

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using simple html dom parser but when I use file_get_html(), it returns empty page, but page is note empty you can check by opening in browser. Here is my code

```
include"11/simple_html_dom.php";
$link = "http://www.flipkart.com/transcend-storejet-25m3-2-5-inch-1-tb-external-hard-disk/p/itmd72p3y3zcsbku?       pid=ACCD72ZXFC6ZRTST&srno=b_1&ref=549d7873-2897-4bd5-8451-776337341be8";

 $html = file_get_html($link);
   if(!empty($html)){
    echo  $html->find("span.fk-font-verybig") ;
   }
    else{
    echo 'file is empty';
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead

Comment: I tried it already but no help

Comment: use file_get_contents and check this -> php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: @Arun allow_url_fopen is on and file_get_contents doesn't work

Comment: reference -> [stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url]

Comment: @user2267099 I had the same issue in a project. The value is coming from json array which you are not able to get via SimpleHtmlParser

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
in your simple_html_dom.php 
Edit this line define('MAX_FILE_SIZE',600000); to define('MAX_FILE_SIZE',900000); or even more according to the size of your file.
This sometimes occurs when your Html file size is larger then what is define so it returns empty without any errors.
I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo $html->find("span.fk-font-verybig");`
try `echo reset( $html->find("span.fk-font-verybig") );`